# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment Health Suspended due to Missing Permissions

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-aws

I'm encountering an issue with my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment where the health status is showing as "Suspended".

Upon investigation, I found that the service role associated with the environment, specifically "arn:aws:iam::69xxxxx03:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role", is missing permissions required to check for managed updates.

This appears to be preventing the environment from functioning properly. I've verified the policies attached to the role, but I'm unsure which specific permissions are needed to resolve this issue.

Could someone please provide guidance on which permissions are required for the Elastic Beanstalk service role to perform health checks and managed updates? Additionally, any insights on how to adjust the role's policies to grant these permissions would be greatly appreciated.

Current permissions policies applyed to aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role:

- AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk
- AWSElasticBeanstalkCustomPlatformforEC2Role
- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleCore
- AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleSNS
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier

Platform
Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.2.2

Thank you in advance for your help!